# Which nvidia to install? Latest from Nvidia.com or from additional drivers?

Tags: nvidia

A very simple question

Which Nvidia driver is best to install?

The latest Nvidia driver from nvidia website which is 346.47

or

Nvidia-331.113 from Additional Drivers tool?

I have updated my kernel version to 3.18.3-031803-generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which drivers to install depends entirely on how you use your system. The `331.113` drivers are generally more stable as they have been extensively tested for the current version of Ubuntu and are much less likely to malfunction than the latest drivers, the `346.47` drivers on the other hand use bleeding-edge technologies that may improve performance of video games and in some cases add additional features not seen in the older drivers, One example of this is that the `331.113` drivers do not support resolutions above 1920x1080 through HDMI while the `346.47` drivers can support additional resolutions but are generally less stable than the `331.113` drivers.

In summary, If you require stability then it is better to use the `331.113` drivers but if you require improved performance for video games or need any additional features provided by the newer drivers then it may be better to go for the `346.47` drivers instead.

Additionally, if you do decide to use the `346.47` drivers then it may to easier to install them using the `xorg-edgers` ppa which will allow you to install the latest 346 drivers using `apt-get install`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Hello there
Thanks for the answer.
I am not planning to play games on Linux yet.
I just want the Linux to work for now so i can learn to use it.